# TypeError at /dashboard/profiles/create/ path_and_rename() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'instance' and 'filename'

Tags: django, typeerror

I am trying to save information from the form created out of the Django model. I am really not much experienced as this is my second project.

Here is my view

```
def profile_create_view(request):
form = ProfileCreateForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save
    form = ProfileCreateForm()
context = {
    'form':form
}
return render(request, 'users/profile', context)
```

my form is here

```
class ProfileCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = [
        'avatar',
        'user_type',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'gender',
        'email',
        'phonenumber',
        'birth_date',]
```

and then my model is here

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = '', default = path_and_rename, blank=True)
provider = 'provider'
requester = 'requester'
user_types = [
    (provider, 'provider'),
    (requester, 'requester'),
   ]
user_type = models.CharField(max_length=155, choices=user_types, default=requester)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
GENDER_MALE = 'Male'
GENDER_FEMALE = 'Female'
OTHER = 'Other'

GENDER_CHOICES = [
    (GENDER_MALE, 'Male'),
    (GENDER_FEMALE, 'Female'),
    (OTHER, 'Other'),
   ]
gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
email = models.EmailField(default='none@email.com')
phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='')
birth_date = models.DateField(default='1975-12-12')
```

Answer (score 1):

Strange things happen in the view function, you have to rebuild it [like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-custom-queryset).

```
def profile_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileCreateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')        
    else:
        form = form(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'manage_authors.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: it seems we are almost there for this answer here is a new error:                              
ValueError at /dashboard/profiles/create/
The view users.views.profile_create_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: User instance must be included, see the updated answer.

Comment: now it has become this error: UnboundLocalError at /dashboard/profiles/create/
local variable 'form' referenced before assignment. and I MUST THANK YOU FOR THIS MUCH HELP YOU ARE OFFERING FOR SURE. THANKS

Comment: local variable 'form' referenced before assignment it means its executing ELSE PART
you can fix that bu putting  **form = ProfileCreateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)** this on top of If condition but that is not the actual problem
form isnt valid or request method is not POST.

Comment: @HemalPatel Thanks though I had tried that before and the error was:             
TypeError at /dashboard/profiles/create/
'ProfileCreateForm' object is not callable
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/profiles/create/
Django Version: 3.2.10
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'ProfileCreateForm' object is not callable
Exception Location: C:\Users\JC\Desktop\cajetanglobalvisas\users\views.py, line 233, in profile_create_view
Python Executable: C:\python3.6\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I had forgotten I solved it by changing the model on avatar from
'avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = '', default = path_and_rename, blank=True)'
to
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'uploads/', default='uploads/default.jpg')